# Meaning of 「内容をテキストのみに適用」

Tags: translation, idioms

In the context of a right-click drop-down menu, what does

> 内容をテキストのみに適用
>
> Apply the contents only as text (?)

mean? At first I thought I thought it meant "paste as text only", but clicking the option doesn't actually paste any text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

適用 never means "paste", and に does not mean "as". ("Paste as text" would have been テキストとして貼り付け, テキストでペースト, etc.)

The literal meaning of 内容をテキストのみ**に**適用 is "Apply only **to** the text". It's difficult to imagine what it really does, but according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/VOICEVOX/voicevox/issues/1353), this is a setting that allows you to edit the text field only and skip the subsequent morphological analysis (parsing).